# Treatment asa binary variable

Tags: r, variables, binary, dplyr

Could anyone may help me to fix this error?

```
Error: The treatment must be a binary variable.
```

Trying keeping on running such following code lines and cannot figure out where the problem is and why this is occurring, although after running the mutate function, which is required mutually by the matchit function.

```
    library(Matching)
    library(MatchIt)
    library(cobalt)
    library(WeightIt)
    library(twang)
    library(tidyverse)
    library(Hmisc)
    library(emmeans)
    library(rms)
    library(rpart) 
    library(randomForest)
    library(survey)
    library(glue)
    library(nnet)    
    
    set.seed(1)
        matching_lg_1 <- map(
          .x = ratios, ~ matchit(
            A ~ B + C + D + E + F + G +
              H + J, data = data %>% 
            mutate(A = if_else(A =='1', 1, 0), .data = cardio_db_matched), 
            distance = "logit", method = "nearest", ratio = .x, caliper = 0.2,
            m.order = "random", replace = FALSE
          )
        ) %>%
          set_names(x = ., nm = c("ratio_1:1", "ratio_1:2"))
```

The variable in the original dataset may assume the following values:

```
1
2
```

Thanks for paying attention.

Comment: I specify that procedure is my treatment variable!!

Comment: Can I ask what version of `MatchIt` you are using?

Comment: same issue here

Comment: @giac You can get the same error if you forget the data argument or specify the wrong data frame. Easy to overlook, if your formula is very long.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem and this is telling you that the `treatment` (`procedure`) does not contain values between 0 and 1. Most likely you have missing values, in that case, set `na.omit()` or check any possible transformation of the variable that leads to it not having just values of 0 and 1.